# How to compress an image with JPEG or PNG in C# in-memory?

Tags: c#, stream, compression, jpeg, emgucv

I am currently working with C# and EmguCV (OpenCV) and want to compress/decompress an image with JPEG/PNG that is currently represented by the `Mat` class. I don't want to store it on disk, just compress it in-memory. The goal is to transfer it by TCP/IP later on.

Some code snippet for the following tasks highly appreciated:

```
A. Compress:   Mat -> JPEG/PNG compressed byte[]
B. Decompress: JPEG/PNG compressed byte[] -> Mat
```

Comment: I haven't used EmguCV, but looking at the documentation, it appears that your Mat object has a Bitmap property.  You can call Save on the Bitmap in order to serialize it directly to a stream (e.g. MemoryStream) in order to get the raw bytes.  The Save function allows you to specify the format (png and jpg allowed).  Going in the other direction, you can call System.Drawing.Image.FromStream() in order to load the bitmap directly from memory.

Comment: @RogerN: That looks very promising! I am going to try out this approach and report back with my results. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: These formats are only compressed when they are stored in a file.  The point of loading an image is to make whatever you do next with it as fast as possible.   Memory is very cheap.  You could arbitrarily use Image.Save() to store it in a MemoryStream.

Comment: OpenCV has "imdecode" and "imencode" exactly for this. Probably emgucv has them, too

Comment: Yes, "imencode" and "imdecode" are available as static members of the CvInvoke class. Thanks so far, I will try both approaches and publish some results here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final code for compressing a `Mat` object with JPG returning a byte array for network transfer:

```
    using Emgu.CV;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;

    private VideoQuality quality;
    private ImageCodecInfo codecInfo;
    private EncoderParameters encoderParameters;

    public byte[] compress(Mat image) {
        using(MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream()) {
            long tstart = Toolkit.CurrentTimeMillis();
            image.Bitmap.Save(memstream, codecInfo, encoderParameters);
            return memstream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private void setVideoQuality(long quality) {
        this.codecInfo = getEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        this.encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);
    }

    private ImageCodecInfo getEncoder(ImageFormat format) {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
        foreach(ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs) {
            if(codec.FormatID == format.Guid) {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And here's the corresponding code for decoding the byte array:

```
    private Image createImage(byte[] bytes) {
        using (MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) {
            memstream.Position = 0;
            return Image.FromStream(memstream, true);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone :-) Thanks for your help!